# Gatsby Link State is lost when I refresh the page

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am sending state data using `state` props in the `Link` component provided Gatsby.

```
<Link
  to={`/photos`}
  state={{ photoData }}
>
  View Photo
</Link>
```

When I Click `View Photo` Link, it goes to `photos` page and I can get the `photoData` from `props.location.state`.
The problem is when I refresh the page, this `photoData` is cleared.
This works well on the `development` mode, so the `photoData` is persisted even after I refresh the `photos` page.
But it doesn't work in the `production` mode.
I was thinking to store the data to redux store but this is over-killing.

Any idea to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I ran the same problem.
In my case it was because I was opening a new tab every time I accessed the link.
One possible way to solve it is to use `window.history.state` (according to this solved issue: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/9091).

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue, and I ended up using a hook that persists the state in local storage. I don't know if you're using hooks, but assuming you are this should solve your problem:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export const usePersistState = (key: string | any, defaultValue: string | boolean | any) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(() => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      const persistedState = window.localStorage.getItem(key);
      return persistedState !== null ? JSON.parse(persistedState) : defaultValue;
    }
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
  }, [key, value]);
  return [value, setValue];
};
```

This sets your state based on a localStorage item, so it should have a boolean value. Then import it into your components, and use it much like `useState`.

```
import { usePersistState } from 'hooks/use-persist-state';

const [state, setState] = usePersistState('localStorageKey', localStorageValue);
```

I've used this to persist data I'm calling from an API, and to show/hide a cookie consent banner, so it's got a lot of uses. Happy coding, hopefully this solves your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Put state in local storage state will definately lost if you refresh the page

Answer (score 0):

State is set during a transition between pages. In other words, it's passed from one page to another. When you refresh the target page, `location.state` will be null as state should come from the previous page.